# Error in JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

When I am using below code :

```
{
   "info":[
      {
         "name": "Adam",
         "address": "Park Street"
      }
    ]
}
```

It is parsing perfectly

but adding on further code like:

```
{
   "info":[
      {
        "name": "Adam",
        "address": "Park Street1"
      },
      {     //<------ getting error here
        "name": "Bob",
        "address": "Park Street2"
      },
      {
        "name": "Clarin",
        "address": "Park Street3"
      }
    ]
}
```

I am getting error : Parse error

Comment: remove that comment _//<------ getting error here_.... it's perfectly valid then `-->` http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: @ dystroy... how to find that?

Comment: @ pXL .... that is intended for this question only

Comment: check the JSON here http://json.parser.online.fr/ . There doesn't seem to be any error.. Share more code

Comment: @Aquarius24 what you have is valid JSON, perhaps the problem is elsewhere? Can you provide any additional code that you are using to process the JSON?

Comment: dystroy is right, theres some mangled whitespace. you dont find it, you just delete the line where the error is, and rewrite it. shouldnt be so hard, its only one curly brace ^^

Comment: Without your comment the json is perfectly alright

Comment: Your json is correct. There might be additional space in your json string.

Comment: May be the error was some hidden spaces.... i replaced the file and it worked :) thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, that I could reproduce by writing a JSON string from scratch and testing it in [jslint.com](http://www.jslint.com/), is related to this bad sequence :

```
{
space
LF
```

Exemple of a bad JSON string :

```
{ 
 "a":3
}
```

If you remove the space, it works.

So you know how to fix it.

Aditional notes :

- it fails both on Chrome and Firefox in jslint.com with default settings
- jslint.com accepts the JSON if you check "messy white space"
- other online parsers might be less strict
- it doesn't fail with Crockford's JavaScript implementation of `JSON.parse` (you can test it [here](http://dystroy.org/JSON.parseMore/)) nor with the native `JSON.parse` of your browser

If you read [the norm](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt?number=4627), it seems that your JSON **is**, in fact, valid :

> These are the six structural characters:
>
> ```
>   begin-array     = ws %x5B ws  ; [ left square bracket
>
>   begin-object    = ws %x7B ws  ; { left curly bracket
>
>   end-array       = ws %x5D ws  ; ] right square bracket
>
>   end-object      = ws %x7D ws  ; } right curly bracket
>
>   name-separator  = ws %x3A ws  ; : colon
>
>   value-separator = ws %x2C ws  ; , comma
> ```
>
> Insignificant whitespace is allowed before or after any of the six 
>   structural characters.
>
> ```
>   ws = *(
>             %x20 /              ; Space
>             %x09 /              ; Horizontal tab
>             %x0A /              ; Line feed or New line
>             %x0D                ; Carriage return
>         )
> ```

The whitespace you have is useless, even for formatting, but it's legal. You'd better remove it but you should probably also tune your parser to be more tolerant, as is the rule.

Answer (score 1):

Check on [jsonlint.com](http://www.jsonlint.com). Your JSON is perfect ... there might be some issue with your editor